# carbon compare date check if date day is equal to current day

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I want to compare if the post date day is equal to the current day. But below example is not working. Do you know why? The date column is of "datetime" type.

```
$post= Post::Query();
…
elseif($range == "week") {
    $post= $post->where('date', <', Carbon::now()->addDays(7));
}
elseif($range == "day") {
    $post= $post->where('date', '=', Carbon::today());
}
....
```

When the user selects the current day in the select menu, no results appear, but select week works.

Comment: `Carbon::today()` includes the time at `00:00:00`

Answer (score 23):

Look for method isSameDay() on [carbon docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):

```
$dt->isSameDay($dt2);
```

Remeber to parse the date, you must use two Carbon objects...

Comment: Unfornately this doesnt work. I parse 2 dates, I print the dates and I see this: 2023-06-27 08:00:00 and 2023-06-29 08:00:00 and yet Carbon thinks its the same day

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, I am assuming that your only comparing to a date.

```
…
elseif($range == "week") {
    $post= $post->whereDate('date', <', Carbon::now()->addDays(7)->format('Y-m-d'));
}
elseif($range == "day") {
    $post= $post->whereDate('date', '=', Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has build in Query Builder functions to work with dates, such as `whereDate`.
So you can do:

```
$post = $post->whereDate('date', '=', Carbon::today());
```

This will make sure the time part of the Carbon date is not included.

Comment: Thanks, but also dont works. With week works with where instead of whereDate.